# Many client connections Ruby

Tags: ruby

Basically, we have a large (100+) number of remote embedded devices that we need to stream data from.

I can connect to any individual remote host with the following code:

```
require 'socket'

socket = TCPSocket.new '192.168.1.115', 8016

loop do
  socket.write("GET_DATA")
  data = socket.read(32)
end

s.close
```

But I want to connect to many of them at once. Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Comment: When you say "at once", do you mean asynchronously? If so, start each connection [in a new thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use threads :

```
ips = ['192.168.1.115', '...', '...']
threads = []

ips.each do |ip|
  threads << Thread.new do
     # Connect here, do some stuff with the socket
  end
end

threads.each { |t| t.join }
```

Note that if you want real threading, you should use Jruby or Ruby >= 1.9, the MRI ruby < 1.9 (standard ruby) threads implementation emulates threading ([green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads)), and does real threading only when one thread is waiting for I/O.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.x and now the stable Ruby 2.0 (YARV based) use *native threads* if supported by OS. On the other hand you have to still fight the GIL.

Comment: @DavidUnric Didn't know that, thanks for the precision, I thought even ruby 2.0 used green threads.